# Unable to utilise complete harddisk space of my laptop with dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, boot-partition

I have 5 sda partitions on the system -

1. sda1 ----> 100M ----> HPFS/NTFS/exFAT.
2. sda2 ----> 97.6G ----> HPFS/NTFS/exFAT (I HAVE WINDOWS IN IT).
3. sda3 ----> 345.6G ----> Linux swap / Solaris.
4. sda4 ----> 488.3G ----> Extended.
5. sda5 ----> 488.3G ----> Linux.
   I am unable to identify out of sda4 or sda5 which one I am using while working with ubuntu OS ? (As the data in ubuntu is very precious, I don't want to lose)
   And secondly then I want to merge this unused 488.3G with either current ubuntu or windows space. How to do this ?

Thanks in advance.
Please help !!

Comment: You have 4 primary partitions (sda1-4) I believe from what you've written, the extended partition (sda4) consists of sda5. An extended partition is a form of *logical partition* which contains no data itself; it's data is in the secondary partition sda5.  The sda4 & sda5 space are both the same area of disk (sda4 = logical, sda5 is how logical space within extended space is used).  Thus I don't believe you have unused space, you're just confused by the *extended* partition which is logical space only.,

Answer (score 1):

As I read your question, you have 4 primary partitions (sda1-4)

The extended partition (sda4) consists of sda5. An extended partition is a form of *logical* partition which contains no data itself; it's space is allocated to secondary partition(s) created within it, ie. sda4 & sda5 space are both the same area of disk.

Thus I don't believe you have unused space, you're just confused by the extended partition.

If you need more information, please check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/PartitioningBasics